# Properties just getters but not setters

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am create a Class which have a UIWebView property. I want to set the properties in its main file, but want to make sure the other developers if use this properties can just get the properties but not rather set it again.

I have looked in @private iVar's but apparently it only regulates dot function not to get set yet if I call [WebView LoadRequest:[NSURLRequest]], the function can still be called from outside of the class.

It be nice to know if there is any work through for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foo.h

```
@interface Foo
@property (retain,readonly) NSString *bar;
@end
```

Foo.m

```
#import "Foo.h"

@interface Foo ()
@property (retain,readwrite) NSString *bar;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bar;
@end
```

Comment: and what about the following line ? foo->bar = @"Huh";

Comment: Put @private prior to the definition of the instance variable

Comment: @dbrajkovic, this is a good way, however I am still able to setText for UILabel in my another Class. This is what I am doing.. [[self.viewController bar] setText:@"yes"]; and it happens to set the text. or [self.viewcontroller.bar setText:@"yes"]; any idea why it be letting me allow to set the properties? I am setting these from appdelegate just for testing. Thanks.

Comment: There is no restriction on the properties of the object. You just can't change the object itself.